# PWM is not controlling the fan, voltage drops | ESP32 4-pin fan driver

Tags: mosfet, mosfet-driver, driver, esp32, fan

I'm know only a little about electronics but I had a try to create a driver for 2 120 mm fans (3 W*2). I have PNP, NPN BJTs and N-channel MOSFET IRF3205 which requires 4 V at the gate to be triggered. The schematic I provided would work for turning on/off (if you change 5Vdd back to 12) but it's not working for manipulation PWM signal. Voltage drops significantly when load is connected.

I don-t have an oscilloscope but I do have a multimeter, so it's only details I can provide.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTmuXv.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: You'll damage Q1 or the ESP32 if you connect Q1's base directly like that. Put a 10k resistance between the ESP32 PWM output and Q1's base. Also, which voltage drops when you connect what to what?

Comment: If your fans have PWM input, can't you just tie directly from your ESP32 into that one without any circuitry? If not, choose a MOSFET with very low Vgsth and run it directly from your ESP32.

Comment: 3.3 V PWM is not sufficient for those ID Colling fans. 5 V drops to less than 2. I have a resistor between GPIO and Q1 base, didn't draw it in the schematic, thanks for the mention. I dont have any FET with low Vgs so I tried to design an amplifier to drive IRF3205 that I have.